# Soma de Registros por grupo

Tags: php, android, mysql

Preciso somar o campo ***valor*** da tabela que estou trabalhando,
porém a soma é feita por blocos onde o id de usuário é o mesmo.

Exemplificando:
Trata-se de um carrinho de compras, cada registro é um produto no carrinho com o id do respectivo cliente.
A soma retornará a soma dos produtos no carrinho de compras de cada usuário.

[image: Tabela Exemplo]

Gostaria de fazer essa soma, ou no SQL diretamente, ou no PHP.

Código da consulta:

```
public function busca(){
    $query = "SELECT CLI.CODCLI, CLI.NOME, CLI.ENDCLI AS ENDERECO, CLI.TELCLI AS TEL, CLI.CELCLI AS CEL, " .
             " PROD.NOMEPROD AS PRODUTO, CAR.QUANTIDADE, CAR.VALOR, CAR.INGREREMOV, " .
             " PAG.NOME AS FORMAPAG, FIN.CODCAR AS NUMPEDIDO, FIN.TROCOPARA AS TROCO " .
             " FROM CARRINHO CAR, CLIENTE CLI, PRODUTO PROD, FINALIZADO FIN, PAGAMENTO PAG " .
             " WHERE CLI.CODCLI = CAR.CODCLI AND " .
             " CAR.CODPROD = PROD.CODPROD AND " .
             " (FIN.CODCAR = CAR.IDCAR AND " .
             " FIN.CODCLI = CAR.CODCLI) AND " .
             " PAG.CODIGO = FIN.FORMAPAG " .
             " ORDER BY FIN.HORA";
             var_dump($query);
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=mizy_sushi_bar; charset=utf8;", "root", "");
    $item = $db->prepare($query);
    $item->execute();
    $count = $item->rowCount();
    if ($count > 0) {
        $vetor[] = array("resultado" => "ok");
        $result = $item->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $pos = $registro = 0;
        foreach ($result as $linha) {
            foreach ($linha as $key=>$value){
                //$keys = array_keys($linha);
                //$valor = $linha[$keys[$pos]];
                $chave = key($linha);
                next($linha);
                array_push(strtolower($vetor[$registro][$key]), $valor);
                $vetor[$registro][strtolower($key)] = $value;
                $pos++;
            }
            $registro++;
        }
        return json_encode($vetor, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    }
}
```

O que é retornado:

```
{
    "0":{
        "resultado":"ok",
        "codcli":"1",
        "nome":"Jhonatan Pereira",
        "endereco":"Endereço completo",
        "tel":"2100000000",
        "cel":"21000000000",
        "produto":"Produto Teste2",
        "quantidade":"3",
        "valor":"90.00",
        "ingreremov":"nenhum",
        "formapag":"DINHEIRO",
        "numpedido":"1",
        "troco":"0.00"
    },
    "1":{
        "codcli":"1",
        "nome":"Jhonatan Pereira",
        "endereco":"Endereço",
        "tel":"2100000000",
        "cel":"21000000000",
        "produto":"Prod Teste",
        "quantidade":"5",
        "valor":"125.00",
        "ingreremov":"nenhum",
        "formapag":"DINHEIRO",
        "numpedido":"1",
        "troco":"0.00"
    }
}
```

OBS.: Nesse caso a terceira linha da tabela não está no JSON devido a outros critérios fora do caso em questão (compra não finalizada).

O que desejo que ele retorne (última linha dos dois objetos):

```
{
    "0":{
        "resultado":"ok",
        "codcli":"1",
        "nome":"Jhonatan Pereira",
        "endereco":"Endereço completo",
        "tel":"2100000000",
        "cel":"21000000000",
        "produto":"Produto Teste2",
        "quantidade":"3",
        "valor":"90.00",
        "ingreremov":"nenhum",
        "formapag":"DINHEIRO",
        "numpedido":"1",
        "troco":"0.00",
        "soma":"215.00"
    },
    "1":{
        "codcli":"1",
        "nome":"Jhonatan Pereira",
        "endereco":"Endereço",
        "tel":"2100000000",
        "cel":"21000000000",
        "produto":"Prod Teste",
        "quantidade":"5",
        "valor":"125.00",
        "ingreremov":"nenhum",
        "formapag":"DINHEIRO",
        "numpedido":"1",
        "troco":"0.00",
        "soma":"215.00"
    }
}
```

OBS.: a redundância da chave "soma" não é problema no momento. O terceiro registro, cujo valor é 60.00, entraria como 60.00 mesmo, por não ter outros registros do mesmo cliente.

Link do arquivo .sql que cria as tabelas e insere os dados:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0HKv_LLOe9SaklJRkZOaW9mSXM/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Tente usar a função sum do sql e agrupar pelo cliente

Comment: Boa, Nayron, deu certo, coloquei um SUM(CAR.VALOR) e antes do ORDER BY coloquei GROUP BY CLI.CODCLI, só isso já resolveu. Responde aí pra eu votar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente usar a função sum do sql e agrupar pelo cliente!